# How do we calculate $\cos (3\pi/4+k\pi)$?

Tags: trigonometry

Can someone help me to compute $\cos(\frac{3 \pi}{4}+\pi k)$?

I know that this is equal to $\cos(\frac{3 \pi}{4}) \cos(\pi k)-\sin(\frac{3 \pi}{4})\sin(\pi k)$, which equals to $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cos(\pi k)-0 \sin(\pi k)$.

How do I proceed? Thank you.

Comment: Find $\cos(\pi k)$

Comment: Calculate the first few values of $\cos(\pi k)$. Do you recognize a pattern? How does it change depending on $k$?

Comment: Please fix the title

Comment: @Clayton I did found some values of cos(pi*k) which were -1,1,-1,1 but i dont know what power to raise (-1). Should it be 1 or 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\cos k\pi = (-1)^{k}$ for integer $k$.

So it simplifies to$$\cos (k\pi+3\pi/4)=\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: Good for ending the question.

Comment: Thanks. You were quicker and I duly upvoted your answer :)

Comment: I would like to thank everyone who helped me solve this question.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** observe that if $k = 0,  2, 4 ...$
$$cos(\pi k) = 1 $$

else if $k = 1, 3, 5, ...$

then:

$$cos(\pi k) = -1 $$

Comment: So is cos(pi*k)=(-1)^(2*k)?

Comment: No, it's (-1)^(k), and was the answer useful?